# I have a docker image that hangs when attempting to create a docker container with no errors or output. Where do I start debugging?

Tags: docker, nginx, npm, vuejs2, deployment

I have a docker image that hangs when attempting to create a docker container with no errors or output.  Any help is appreciated!

Here is my docker file:

```
# base image
FROM node:18.16-alpine as builder

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /client

# Copy the package.json and install dependencies
COPY ./client/package*.json .

RUN npm install -g npm@9.6.7
RUN npm install --omit=dev --force
RUN npm install @vue/cli --force

# install and cache client dependencies
COPY ./client .

# build client
RUN npm run build


# Start nginx to serve Vue client
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-build
COPY ./client/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Remove default nginx index page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy files from builder stage
COPY --from=builder /client/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

As you can probably see, I am trying to run a Vue app through nginx.  This Dockerfile does create an image using the command:

```
cd ~/app
sudo docker build -t app-client -f ./client/Dockerfile .
```

However, when I run:

```
sudo docker run app-client
```

It just hangs with no errors or anything. I don't even know where to begin debugging this problem.

EDIT:  Here is my nginx.conf file as well

```
events {
    worker_connections 1000;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

This project was setup using the Vue cli. The project runs just fine on the development server using:

```
npm run serve
```

from within the app/client directory.

EDIT 2: So it looks like the container does run, however, it doesn't send or receive traffic.  Docker ps says that the container is running with the correct open port, but when I type that port it does not serve the app.  No errors or other outputs are generated either.

Side-quest:  I have to use --force on my npm install statements because otherwise, I get a bunch of errors that halt the build process.  If that could be sorted out as well I would rest easier at night.

Comment: I just thought I probably should include my nginx.conf file as well.  Here is my configuration.